# docker using wrong angular environment file

Tags: angular, docker, production-environment

I want to be able to toggle between Urls so that when I run my angular app locally for development I use the url of my localhost, and when I run it the way I would for production in a docker container it is using the url of the actual api.

I thought that the most straightforward way to do this was using angular's built in environment files.

however, even though I am building my angular project in the container using the "--prod" flag, it still uses the url from the development environment file.

here are the relevant files-

dockerfile:

```
FROM node:16-alpine as builder

WORKDIR /app

COPY . .

RUN npm install
RUN npm run build --prod


FROM nginx:alpine
COPY --from=builder /app/dist/movie-web-app /usr/share/nginx/html
```

environment.development.ts:

```
export const environment = {
    production:false,
    apiUrl:"https://localhost:7052/api/"
};
```

environment.ts:

```
export const environment = {
    production:true,
    apiUrl:"https://localhost:49157/api/"

};
```

(ignore the fact that they are both currently set to ports of localhost, the problem is that the app is making calls to 7052 and not 49157)

Any direction as to why this is happening and how I can fix it/ a better way to toggle between urls, would be amazing.
thanks!

Comment: You do need to configure target-specific file replacements for your env files. The docs are quite helpful for this: [Configure target-specific file replacements](https://angular.io/guide/build#configure-target-specific-file-replacements)

Comment: but that already exists by default for the env files for production vs development builds. Its in my angular.json, but somehow it isn't working in the docker build.

Comment: You need to use ng build --config production instead of npm run build --prod.

Comment: I tried that now, but it is still calling the development url.

Comment: whats the content of angular.json?